# (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myuser" FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myuser"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am trying to build a simple web app using flask and PostgreSQL. I was using SQLALchemy and psycopg2 to complete the task but I got stuck at this error for a long time. I have my configuration set as follows:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =  "postgresql://myuser:c2yQdn3e@localhost:5432/hello"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

My database name was "hello" and my user name is "myuser". I have even entered the password correctly but still it is showing this error. I have looked for a lot of solution on the net and tried everything but I am still getting this error. My pg_hba.conf file looks like this

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You could try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your connection URL and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: In the `pg_hba.conf` you show all the `host` lines are set to `trust` so a password will be ignored. Are you sure that is the correct file for the database you are connecting to? Can you connect using `psql`?  Are you sure that `myuser` actually exists in the database? **Add answers as update to your question. My suspicion is either you are not connecting to the database cluster you think you are or the user name is not what you think it is.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have also converted the `host` part to `md5` as well, but it still didn't work and regarding the other question I was able to connect using `psql`. Here is the conninfo regarding the same. `You are connected to database "hello" as user "myuser" via socket in "/tmp" at port "5432".`

Comment: @GordThompson, this method didn't work as well.

Comment: Please add answers as update to your question so people don't have to work through the comments for relevant information.  1) Did you `reload` the server after making the `pg_hba.conf` file? 2) In the `psql` case you are using `local` not `host` so it is not the same as your `SQLAlchemy` case. Use the same connection parameters and try again. Also show your complete `psql` command line.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sure, I will make changes in the question (actually I am not very frequent on stack overflow)
1.  I did reload the server
2.  I am not able to understand but here is my complete psql command
`shipsy@shipsys-Air ~ % psql -d hello -U myuser`
`Password for user myuser: `
`psql (14.2)`
`Type "help" for help.`

`hello=# \conninfo`
`You are connected to database "hello" as user "myuser" via socket in "/tmp" at port "5432".`
`hello=# `

Comment: You need to do `psql -d hello -U myuser -h localhost` to replicate your `SQLAlchemy` connection and see if that works?